# ImproperlyConfigured at / - /static/ isn't a storage module

Tags: python, django

I am trying to upload a file.

this is my model.

```
def custom_path(instance, filename):
 return '/'.join(['upload',instance.student.user.username,filename])

class Doc(models.Model):
 uploadtime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
 datei = models.FileField(upload_to=custom_path,default='')
 student = models.ForeignKey(Student,related_name='students_file')
 title = models.TextField()
 desc = models.TextField()
 def __unicode__(self):
     return self.title
```

and this is my views.py

```
def hochgeladen_danke(request):
 if request.FILES.get('file'):
    student = request.user.get_profile()
    student.students_file.create(datei=request.FILES.get('file'),title='t',desc='t')
    return render_to_response('upload.html',{},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

my html:

```
<form action="/hochgeladen_danke/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   {% csrf_token %}
   File: <input type="file" name="file"/>
   <button type="submit">upload</button>                
</form>
```

my settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "media")
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "static")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

when i try to upload a file. it is saying:

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /hochgeladen_danke/ 
/static/ isn't a storage module.
```

i dont know why this is happening. my custom_path seems to be right.

my urls.py:

```
..
url(r'^hochgeladen_danke/$','hochgeladen_danke',name='hochgeladen_danke'),
)

if settings.DEBUG:
  urlpatterns = patterns('',
  url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
    {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
  url(r'', include('django.contrib.staticfiles.urls')),
) + urlpatterns
```

Comment: do you want to upload to `/upload` or `/static/upload` ?

Comment: did you configure STATICFILES_DIRS?

Comment: @karthikr, to ``/upload`` under ``/media/``

Comment: Yes, you would need to configure [static files directory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/#using-django-contrib-staticfiles) ?

Comment: @karthikr, I'm really not sure it's obligatory. doniyor, Could you perhaps also share your urls.py?

Comment: what is your `settings.DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE`?

Comment: @kroolik, oh it is ``/static/``. should i change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is wrong with your `settings.DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE`.

The exception you have provided comes from [django.core.files.storage@272](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4.5/django/core/files/storage.py#L272), which in turn comes from `default_storage` right below, and [django.db.models.files@221](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4.5/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L221). The constructor is called in your view, causing the exception to be thrown.

Comment: kroolik the Great! great help, thank you, working like a charm!